# I need to select and delete the hdfs files older than 100 days in hive partitioned table using UNIX shell script?

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

[Link hdfs files (image/screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOM4O.png):

```
Below are the sample hdfs paths with partitioning details :

/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/year=2011/month=10/day=1
/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/year=2011/month=10/day=2
/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/year=2011/month=10/day=3
```

---

First I need select the files older than 100 days from current day, and then I need to delete using `hdfs rm command`.

I don't want alter table statement method for deleting those partitions.
How can I use `for` loop for selection and deletion using shell scripting?

Since I am developing this in **[shellscript](/questions/tagged/shellscript)**, can you please help on this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching how to get the date 100 days ago? Or string formatting for the file path? Note: it'd be easier to use the Java API directly to do this

Comment: I need to search the hdfs files for 100 days ago , Files are portioned with year and month and date 
/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/year=2017/month=9/day=18
/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/year=2018/month=9/day=15
/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/year=2018/month=10/day=2
/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/year=2019/month=9/day=27
like above , 100 days ago file from today

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235019/delete-files-older-than-10days-on-hdfs

Comment: I understand the question. I'm asking what you've tried. This isn't entirely a Hadoop problem. How would you generate that list of files in just bash? Forget hdfs, you're just formatting a string

Comment: you are right @cricket_007 ..!!! , I need a shell script to get these files , I tried with shell only and i unable get the correct results

..............Gary Bowdridge , in u r comment ticket , its is taking creation date is input but we need date in file name , since hive table partitioned with date 
needs to take that date as a input for our shell script

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include what you've tried? Also, if you're more comfortable with a different programming language, then use it instead to generate your list of files. Again it's just string formatting and some date math. Reading a file into a bash script is easier than doing everything in one script